# angularjs:-how to implement click on div for image to be loaded

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, onclick

Hi I am trying to implement a click event after the div is loaded..

the following is my html file:-

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="grid-12">
    <div class="row" id="grid-121">
      <div class="col-sm-12" style="border: 1px solid;min-height: 300px;">
        <input ng-click="onChange($file)" ng-show="$state.current.name==='admin'" type="file" ngf-select="" ng-model="picFile" name="file" ngf-accept="'image/*'" required="">
        <i ng-show="myForm.file.$error.required">*required</i>
        <img ngf-src="picFile" class="img img-responsive">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus pull-right deleteBtn" ng-click="deleteRow($index, layout)"></span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </script>
```

The following is my script file:-

```
$scope.onChange = function(files) {
        $scope.picFile = true;

        if (files) {
          Upload.upload({
            url: 'https://staging.abc.com/v1/admin/images',
            headers: {
              'Access-Token': 'xxx',
              'Api-Token': 'xxx'
            },
            // image:{imageable_type: "DesktopGrid"},
            data: {
              image: {
                image: files,
                imageable_type: 'DesktopGrid'
              }
            }
            //  data: {file: file, 'username': $scope.username}
          }).then(function(resp) {
            console.log('Success ' + resp.config.data.file.name + 'uploaded. Response: ' + resp.data);
          }, function(resp) {
            console.log('Error status: ' + resp.status);
          }, function(evt) {
            var progressPercentage = parseInt(100.0 * evt.loaded / evt.total);
            //console.log('progress: ' + progressPercentage + '% ' + evt.config.data.image.image.name);
            // the above code is to show for percentage code push in console
          });
        }
      }
      // code written below to get the entire html element and display it..implement on click
    $http.get('url').then(function(response) {
      var raw_html = response.data;
      var raw_angular = angular.element(document.querySelector('#panel_html'));

      var angular_body_html = raw_angular.context.innerHTML
        // console.log(angular_body_html) // this is getting the actual html

      $scope.angular_body_html = raw_angular.context.innerHTML
        //  console.log(angular_body_html) // this is getting the actual html
    });

    //The below is the HTML used to save the html template
    $scope.submit = function(file) {
      debugger;
      if ($scope.myForm.$valid && $scope.selectedImages.length > 0) {
        $scope.upload($scope.picFile);
        var raw_angular = angular.element(document.querySelector('#panel_html'));
        $scope.angular_body_html = raw_angular.context.innerHTML;

       var data = jsona;

        $http.post('http://192.168.3.333/v1/admin/statics/upload_home', data, function() {}, "json")
          .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            console.log("The data is" + data + "The status is" + status + "The header is" + headers + "The config is" + config)
            $scope.mainHomeData = data; 
          })
          .error(function(data, status, header, config) {
            $scope.ResponseDetails = "Data: " + data +
              "<hr />status: " + status +
              "<hr />headers: " + header +
              "<hr />config: " + config;
          });
        alert("condition satisfied")
      }
    };
    $scope.clickbutton = function() {
      console.log($scope.angular_body_html);
    };

    $scope.updateValue = function(item, newName) {
      item.name = newName;
    };

    $scope.AppendText = function() {
      var myEl = angular.element(document.querySelector('#admincopy'));
      myEl.append($scope.angular_body_html);
    };
    // have to give the latest path to upload the images..working and going inside the function
    $scope.imageArray = [];
    $scope.upload = function(file) {
      var cont = document.getElementsByClassName('img img-responsive');
      for (var i = 0; i < cont.length; i++) {
        var image_source = cont[i].currentSrc;

        $scope.imageArray.push(image_source);
        console.log($scope.imageArray);
      }


      // console.log(cont);
    };

    function isInArray(value, array) {
      return array.indexOf(value) > -1;
    }
    // for multiple files:

    $scope.opencard = [];
    $scope.image_imp = {}

    $scope.deleteRow = function(index, layout) {
      $scope.selectedLayouts.splice(index, 1);
    }
```

As we can see from the above file I am having a button event to call the onChange function..this function is used to select the file and the call an api to save the image for further use..

However want to call the function when the div is empty or when the image is present in the div.

If I try and call the click event on the main div..I am getting able to call the function via ng-click..Am stuck on this

Please help me out with this..thanks

Comment: You should never use all these `document.querySelector` in controller. Makes you code pretty smelly.

Comment: @dfsq any idea how to implement the above issue